# Picking the value with the highest severity using batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a CSV file in the following format:

```
Group   Test    Result
----------------------
GROUP1  Test1   Amber
GROUP1  Test1   Amber
GROUP1  Test2   Red
Group1  Test3   Amber
Group1  Test4   Green
Group2  Test1   Amber
Group2  Test2   Amber
Group3  Test1   Green
Group3  Test2   Amber
...
```

Using a batch file I'm trying to determine the cumulative result of each Group listed above. For each group the cumulative result is the result with the highest severity (`Red` most severe, `Amber` less severe, `Green` least severe). Following this logic one would expect:

```
Group1 cumulative result = Red
Group2 cumulative result = Amber
Group3 cumulative result = Amber
...
```

The file could have a number of such groups (not just 3)

Now I would like the batch file to output to a text file containing in the following format:

```
Group1,Group2,Group3
Red,Amber,Amber
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how I might do this? I'm thinking a `for /f` loop would be involved.

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set Green=1
set Amber=2
set Red=3
rem Read file lines and process they
for /F "tokens=1-3" %%a in (thefile.csv) do (
   rem Initialize this "group" vector element with zero
   if not defined group[%%a] set group[%%a]=0
   rem Convert "word" severity to a number between 1 and 3
   set severity=!%%c!
   rem Store the cumulative result for this group
   if !severity! gtr !group[%%a]! set group[%%a]=!severity!
)
rem Convert cumulative group numeric results to "word" results
set Severity[1]=Green
set Severity[2]=Amber
set Severity[3]=Red
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set group[') do (
   set group[%%a]=!Severity[%%b]!
)
rem Assemble group names in one line and show they:
set result=
for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set group[') do (
   set result=!result!%%a,
)
echo %result:~0,-1%
rem Assemble group cumulative results in one line and show they:
set result=
for /F "tokens=3 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set group[') do (
   set result=!result!%%a,
)
echo %result:~0,-1%
```